# How to stop transform position when condition meets in unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I need someone to help me with transform.position in Unity3d. I am trying to stop tranform.position when M key is pressed. I tried with the below mentioned code but it's still moving in same speed.

```
public class Scroll : MonoBehaviour
{
    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (PlayerController.isDead) return;
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.M))
        {
            transform.position += PlayerController.player.transform.forward * -20f * Time.deltaTime;
        }
        else
        {
            transform.position += PlayerController.player.transform.forward * -5f * Time.deltaTime;
        }
        if (PlayerController.currentPlatform == null) return;
        if (PlayerController.currentPlatform.tag == "stairsUp")
            this.transform.Translate(0, -0.06f, 0);
        if (PlayerController.currentPlatform.tag == "stairsDown")
            this.transform.Translate(0, 0.06f, 0);

    }
}
```

In normal condition transform.position is working but when I press the M key it should be slow down as much as it should look like its stopped now. I think Else condition is running perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you don't have any other interfering code and try this (only this in your update (FixedUpdate) methed to stop your transform from moving.

```
if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.M))
  return;
```

You should be able to use `Input.GetKey` in `FixedUpdate`, however for `Input.GetKeyDown` / `Input.GetKeyDown` I would recommend using `Update` to make sure no events get lost.

If that does not work, try to add this to a cube (or something visual) in your scene. This will certainly move and the stop as soon as you press M.

```
using UnityEngine;

public class MoveTest : MonoBehaviour
{
    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.M))
            return;

        transform.position += Vector3.forward * -5f * Time.deltaTime;
    }
}
```

--- OLD ANSWER BEFORE UPDATED POST --

You should use `GetKey` instead

> Returns true while the user holds down the key identified by name.
>   https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetKey.html

You are using `GetKeyDown` that only returns true during the frame you pressed the key resulting in slowdown only one frame  ¬

> Returns true during the frame the user starts pressing down the key
>   identified by name.

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetKeyDown.html

Comment: Nothing works. Platform is not stopping on M key is pressed. It keeps going

Comment: Then your code is not running correctly or you have other code that is moving the gameobject. Any errors?

Comment: This works now. The only problem is now it should be stopped until M key finishes the function. When I hold the M key it is stopped but when I release the M key, the platforms start moving.

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to stop tranform.position when M key is pressed.

Currently you reach your `if` block exctly in **one single frame** namely the moment the key goes down the first time. [`Input.GetKeyDown`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetKeyDown.html)

> Returns true **during the frame** the user starts pressing down the key identified by the key KeyCode enum parameter.

For continues executions you would want to use [`Input.GetKey`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetKey.html) which

> Returns true **while the user holds down the key** identified by the key KeyCode enum parameter.

```
if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.M))
{
    // you will have to adjust the multiplicators
    transform.position += PlayerController.player.transform.forward * -0.00001f * Time.deltaTime;
}
else
{
    transform.position += PlayerController.player.transform.forward * -0.1f * Time.deltaTime;
}
```

Btw if you really want to `stop` the movement as you say you would probably rather simply use

```
if(!Input.GetKey(KeyCode.M))
{
    transform.position += PlayerController.player.transform.forward * -0.1f * Time.deltaTime;
}
```

and do nothing while `M` stays pressed

---

Note that your code is frame-rate dependent and you always should use [`* Time.deltaTime`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-deltaTime.html) for converting your values from `Units / frame` into `Units / second`

Comment: It slow down the speed even M key is not pressed. FYI the code is written under FixedUpdate() function. In my project player is stick at one position and I am moving platforms in the negative direction.